# How to bind the data with seperate headers using reactive forms in Angular8

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

[DEMO 2](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-68jk6d?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Hi i am using Angular8 reactive forms. In this, i need to bind data with respect to the array name given in the output. Initially i was getting all response as one array of objects but now, it has got differenciated with headers, so i need to bind data accordingly.

i have attached demo with all necessary codings.

TS output:

```
public data = {
    businessLineGroup: {
      'Builders Risk': [
        {
          id: 65,
          prospectCode: 99000130,
          agentCode: null,
          competitorId: 32,
          policyTypeId: 244,
          competitorName: 'w4-ALL RISKS-DIST.OF COL.-Builders Risk',
          quoteCount: '5454',
          policyCount: '25',
          writtenPremium: '56.00',
          isTrack: true,
          isEdit: false,
        },
      ],
      'Commercial Monoline': [
        {
          id: 64,
          prospectCode: 99000130,
          agentCode: null,
          competitorId: 31,
          policyTypeId: 245,
          competitorName:
            'UNITED HOME INS CO-ALL RISKS-ARKANSAS-Commercial Monoline',
          quoteCount: '4566',
          policyCount: '24',
          writtenPremium: '45.00',
          isTrack: true,
          isEdit: false,
        },
        {
          id: 69,
          prospectCode: 99000130,
          agentCode: null,
          competitorId: 37,
          policyTypeId: 245,
          competitorName: 'ug fixes-AMWINS-DELAWARE-Commercial Monoline',
          quoteCount: '524',
          policyCount: '62',
          writtenPremium: '564.00',
          isTrack: false,
          isEdit: false,
        },
      ],
      'Commercial Package': [
        {
          id: 67,
          prospectCode: 99000130,
          agentCode: null,
          competitorId: 34,
          policyTypeId: 246,
          competitorName:
            'Nationwide Mutual Insurance Company-AMWINS-DELAWARE-Commercial Package',
          quoteCount: '452',
          policyCount: '52',
          writtenPremium: '45.00',
          isTrack: false,
          isEdit: false,
        },
      ],
    },
  };
```

binding method:

```
private getOpportunitiesList() {
    this.opportunityList = Object.keys(this.data.businessLineGroup);
    if (this.opportunitesx && this.opportunitesx.controls) {
      this.opportunitesx.controls = [];
    }
    let amount: any;
    for (let i = 0; i < this.opportunitesx.length; i++) {
      if (this.opportunityList[i].quoteCount) {
        let a = new Intl.NumberFormat().format(
          this.opportunityList[i].quoteCount
        );
        this.opportunityList[i].quoteCount = a;
      }
      this.opportunityList[i].isEdit = false;
    }
    for (let lang of this.opportunityList) {
      let group = this.createOpportunityInformation();
      group.get('competitorId').setValue(lang.competitorId);
      group.get('competitorId').disable();
      group.get('quoteCount').setValue(lang.quoteCount);
      group.get('quoteCount').disable();
      group.get('policyCount').setValue(lang.policyCount);
      group.get('policyCount').disable();
      group.get('writtenPremium').setValue(lang.writtenPremium);
      group.get('writtenPremium').disable();
      group.get('isTrack').setValue(lang.isTrack);
      group.get('isEdit').setValue(false);
      group.get('isTrack').disable();
      group.get('id').setValue(lang.id);
      group.get('id').disable();
      this.opportunitesx.push(group);
    }
    this.preventOpportunityEmpty();
  }
```

HTML:

```
<div
  class="table-responsive mb-3"
  [formGroup]="opportunitiesForm"
  [ngClass]="{ scroll: opportunityList?.length > 3 }"
  id="panel1"
  *ngIf="opportunitiesForm"
>
  <table class="table table-hover accordion-table" id="searchList">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th class="width25" scope="col">&nbsp;</th>
        <th
          scope="col"
          *ngFor="let field of opportunityListDetails"
          class="{{ field.class }}"
        >
          {{ field.displayName }}
        </th>
        <th scope="col">Actions</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody formArrayName="opportunitesx">
      <tr
        *ngFor="
          let item of opportunitiesForm.get('opportunitesx')['controls'];
          let i = index
        "
        [formGroupName]="i"
      >
        <td class="width25">
          <span *ngIf="opportunitesx.controls[i]['controls'].competitorId.value"
            ><i
              (mouseenter)="onOpenCompetitorDetails(item)"
              id="competitorInfo"
              class="fa fa-info-circle info-font-size"
            ></i
          ></span>
        </td>
        <td class="width250">
          <select
            class="custom-select drop"
            formControlName="competitorId"
            [ngClass]="{
              'is-invalid':
                submitted &&
                opportunitesx.controls[i]['controls'].competitorId.errors
            }"
            id="competitorId"
          >
            <option disabled="" value="">Choose Competitor</option>
            <option
              *ngFor="let competitor of competitorDropdown"
              [value]="competitor.id"
              title="competitor.value"
            >
              {{ competitor.value }}
            </option>
          </select>
          <div
            *ngIf="
              submitted &&
              opportunitesx.controls[i]['controls'].competitorId.errors
            "
            class="invalid-feedback"
          >
            <div
              *ngIf="
                opportunitesx.controls[i]['controls'].competitorId.errors
                  .required
              "
            >
              Competitor is required
            </div>
          </div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <input
            type="text"
            class="form-control"
            placeholder="Quote Count"
            formControlName="quoteCount"
            maxlength="4"
          />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input
            type="text"
            class="form-control"
            placeholder="Policy Count"
            formControlName="policyCount"
            allowNumberOnly
            maxlength="4"
          />
        </td>
        <td class="width165">
          <input
            type="text"
            class="form-control"
            placeholder="Written Premium"
            formControlName="writtenPremium"
          />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input
            type="checkbox"
            style="width: auto;"
            formControlName="isTrack"
          />
        </td>
        <td class="width125">
          <button
            class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-table"
            title="Close"
            (click)="clearOpportunity(i, opportunitesx.controls[i]['controls'])"
            *ngIf="
              opportunitesx.controls[i]['controls'].isEdit.value ||
              opportunitesx.controls[i]['controls'].id.value == 0
            "
          >
            Close
          </button>
          <button
            class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-table ml-1"
            title="Edit"
            (click)="
              editOpportunityDetails(i, opportunitesx.controls[i]['controls'])
            "
            *ngIf="
              !opportunitesx.controls[i]['controls'].isEdit.value &&
              opportunitesx.controls[i]['controls'].id.value > 0
            "
          >
            Edit
          </button>
          <button
            class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-table ml-1"
            title="Save"
            type="button"
            *ngIf="
              opportunitesx.controls[i]['controls'].isEdit.value ||
              opportunitesx.controls[i]['controls'].id.value == 0
            "
            [disabled]="!this.opportunitesx.controls[i].dirty"
            (click)="saveOpportunityDetails(i)"
          >
            Save
          </button>
          <button
            class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-table ml-1"
            title="Delete"
            *ngIf="opportunitesx.controls[i]['controls'].id.value > 0"
            [disabled]="
              opportunitesx.controls[i]['controls'].isEdit.value &&
              opportunitesx.controls[i]['controls'].id.value > 0
            "
            type="button"
            (click)="
              deleteOpportunityDetails(i, opportunitesx.controls[i]['controls'])
            "
          >
            Delete
          </button>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

[![Image][2]][2]

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vwo8rt?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: What is the issue you are facing?

Comment: i am not able to bind, i used object keys for pushing data inside the form but couldnt

Comment: I donot see the code where you have used object.keys. Also opportunityList is an object you need to use the individual property to iterate over that.

Comment: i have updated my code and in demo as well, all contents are coming as empty.

Comment: Please check demo2, i have updated my code and here issue is that i am not able to save record during update as it is throwing error and i am failing to add the array name as headers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are iterating over the wrong variable, `opportunityList` is not an array, you need to fetch nested keys and loop over it. To show header name you can add two controls in your `formGroup` and set values like below:

```
const dataArray = [];
let obj: any = {};
Object.keys(this.opportunityList.businessLineGroup).forEach((item,index) => {
  this.opportunityList.businessLineGroup[item].forEach((subItem,subIndex) => {
    obj = subItem;
    obj.header = item;
    if(subIndex == 0){
      obj.showHeader = true;
    }else {
      obj.showHeader = false;
    }
    dataArray.push(obj);
  });
});
```

loop over this array to generate form control.

```
for (let lang of dataArray){
}
```

Link to [Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-u4gvgv?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

PS: I have updated the link to demo. To show headers you will have to remove table. For your edit/new functionality you can do the similar changes.

Comment: Thanks for response, we are almost there, but i need headers like, the first row is "Builders Risk" like this has one object inside this array name, and "Commercial Monoline" has 2 objects inside that like wise i need

Comment: if i use, Object.keys(this.data.businessLineGroup) i get 3 names, "Builders Risk", "Commercial Monoline" and "Commercial Package", so objects under respective names must be binded, its like these 3 will be headers and objects in these array will come below as in image

Comment: this will be only for display purpose right, your underlying form group can stay as is ?

Comment: yes i need to display as given in image, it must come under respective headers

Comment: and here i have inline edit and add functionality, so when trying to update i am not able to send data i am getting error, so for this purpose we need to capture and show which array name is getting binded and getting edited.

Comment: i have added demo2 as well for your reference

Comment: I have update the Answer and in the the demo I have done enough changes for your understanding

Comment: Thanks for updating, i will check and get back to you

Comment: Thanks a lot, it really helped me a lot, i have done some more changes as per my requirement and shared in demo link here, i need your help in this, https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-68jk6d?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: in the new link, i have created it along with headers in table, but for second header, it has 2 objects, so instead of calling header 2 times can that header be made to appear one time as in image?

Comment: it is appearing only once, what u want to do ? just do some styling and that's it. Please  accept and upvote the answer, if it helped u. Thanks

Comment: Yes i have accepted and voted your answer, you didnt got points for this?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238457/discussion-between-bhrungarajni-and-yogendrar).

Comment: Sure let's connect

Comment: Hi @YogendraR, i need some help with this question

Comment: can you pls help with this question, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71231436/how-to-bring-new-row-to-top-when-clicked-on-add-new-using-angular8-reactive-form